# Strange overhangs in the roots between mtpro2 and newtxmath

Tags: packages, mtpro, newtxmath, sqrt, root

Executing this MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt{2}$
\end{document}
```

with this output,

[image]

you can see an overhang, marked with a green rectangle, between the root symbol and the horizontal line (with zoom 2563 %). The same happens when you use `mtpro2` package (v. lite),

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt{2}$
\end{document}
```

The overhang is less apparent because the zoom is of the 3844 %.

[image]

Since `newtxmath` and `mtpro2` are two different packages the root symbols are different.

> My question is as follows: *why are there these overhangs*?

**Addendum**: I have seen the .pdf files and with Acrobat Reader to **2400%**, for the first code I see always the overhang.

[image]

The same happen with the second code with the same resolution to the **2400 %**.

[image]

Comment: the root is made by joining a character from the font for the left "tick" and a rule drawn by tex for the horizontal bar, with most fonts the join is visible at some zoom levels.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And no one had thought about aligning it perfectly? :-) I too had thought they were union of two parts. Thank you very much for your kindness.

Comment: it's hard as tex has no control over which pixels the font renderer chooses to make black for the left part although perhaps the newtx one you show could be tweaked a bit

Comment: I cannot see the issue with the first example on my machine. I suspect a problem of the PDF viewer.

Comment: @egreg At this moment I write with the smartphone that I not like absolutely because without line. The screenshots are taken from Texworks and now that I think I have not see the pdf file. Thank you very much for your comment. For the 2nd example is there the overhang..?

Comment: I tried the first example and zoomed in to 2300%, and the root looks ok. At some resolutions, there seems to be a step, but either it smoothes out when waiting a fraction of a second (apparently the viewer increases successively the resolution, to quickly show a preview), or when zooming in even further. To me it seems like an artefact of the rendering engine of the viewer.

Comment: @gernot thank you very much and I reciprocate your attention to my question.

Comment: @egreg Hi, I have used the Acrobat Reader and I see the same problem.

Comment: @gernot Hi, also to you....I have put an addendum.